# Replace outdated WC_Order_Item_Meta in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, deprecated, orders

With Woocommerce, I am using a plugin to export data to an excel file but it keeps telling me that it is deprecated, would there be a way to replace those two lines to make the code work:

```
$product = $order_details->get_product_from_item($item);

$meta = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item, $product );

$meta_html = $meta->display( true, true , '_', ' | ' );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since WC version 3, the `WC_Order` method `get_product_from_item( $item )` is outdated, deprecated and has been replaced by:

```
$product = $item->get_product();
```

and `$item` is now an object from new `WC_Order_Item_Product` class, where properties can't be accessed directly, just as `WC_Order` or `WC_Product` objects too. Instead you should need to use all available methods for those classes.

> Everything has changed deeply since WooCommerce version 3, regarding Orders, products and many other things. The `WC_Order_Item_Meta` class has been deprecated and `wc_display_item_meta` function is used instead.

So your code should be simply:

```
 $meta_html = wc_display_item_meta( $item, array( 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 
    'separator' => ' | ', 'echo' => false, 'autop' => false ) );
```

This should work if all other code has been updated for Woocommerce version 3+.